# iOS - Show InterstitialAd inside custom UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, swift, interstitial

I want to display a InterstitialAd in a custom UIView with a "Next" button.

When I display the Ad on the full screen it works fine. Like this:

```
interstitial.presentInView(self.view)
```

I created a view inside the ViewController. This view should display the Ad. So i connected the `UIView` in the storyboard and changed the code to:

```
interstitial.presentInView(self.iAdView)
```

The console prints that everything is working fine. The iAd is loading without any errors.
But the Ad doesn't appear inside the custom `UIView`.

Does the InterstitialAd only work on full screen? And if yes, is there a way to show a big ad in a custom view?

Thanks